# MS Access query with multiple joins returning duplicate rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, duplicates

I am working with Access to query multiple tables that have passenger info in them. I've been able to distill this down to what I think is causing the issue, but I am unsure how to fix it.

Essentially there are three tables:

PASSENGERS

```
ID   | PASSENGER_NAME | COST_CENTER
-------------------------------------
1    | John Wright    | 31231       
2    | Cheryl Brown   | 54555       
3    | Adam Yang      | 65655
```

FARE_LEVEL

```
ID   | TICKET_NUMBER  | PASSENGER_NAME | TICKET_AMT | IS_REFUND
---------------------------------------------------------------
1    | 14325435       | John Wright    | $632.64    | 0    
2    | 46746745       | Adam Yang      | $797.32    | 0  
3    | 45354434       | Cheryl Brown   | $2331.00   | 0  
4    | 67876456       | Cheryl Brown   | $990.11    | 0     
5    | 34654546       | Adam Yang      | $552.71    | 0  
6    | 14325435       | John Wright    | -$632.64   | 1    
7    | 87989879       | John Wright    | $123.11    | 0  
8    | 99124324       | Adam Yang      | $1114.42   | 0  
9    | 77231235       | Adam Yang      | $6232.32   | 0
```

INCENTIVE_LOG

```
ID   | PASSENGER_NAME | INCENTIVE_AMT
-------------------------------------
1    | Adam Yang      | $1000.00       
2    | Cheryl Brown   | $1000.00       
3    | John Wright    | $1000.00   
4    | John Wright    | $1000.00       
5    | John Wright    | $1000.00
```

I am using this query to join them:

```
SELECT
PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME,
Sum(FARE_LEVEL.TICKET_AMT) AS SumOfFARES,
Count(INCENTIVE_LOG.INCENTIVE) AS CountOfINCENTIVE,
Sum(INCENTIVE_LOG.INCENTIVE) AS SumOfINCENTIVE
FROM (PASSENGERS LEFT OUTER JOIN FARE_LEVEL ON PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME = FARE_LEVEL.PASSENGER_NAME)
INNER JOIN INCENTIVE_LOG ON PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME = INCENTIVE_LOG.PASSENGER_NAME
GROUP BY PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME;
```

The result I am looking for is the sum of all fares for each passenger in the PASSENGER table as well as the sum of all incentives taken for each passenger in the PASSENGER table. So for "John Wright" I would hope to see

```
PASSENGER_NAME | SumOfFares | CountOfIncentive | SumOfIncentive
---------------------------------------------------------------
John Wright    | $123.11    | 3                | $3000.00
```

Instead I am getting get a result that seems to double count. When I change the GROUP BY to

```
GROUP BY PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME, INCENTIVE_LOG.ID, FARE_LEVEL.ID;
```

I can see all of the duplicated rows that it is summing in error. It appears to be creating a row for every combination of FARE_LEVEL and INCENTIVE row that corresponds to a passenger so if someone had 7 fares and 3 incentives it would create 21 rows.

I am fairly certain the issue is in my join, but I am not sure how to fix it.

**EDIT:
I was able to solve the issue by creating two subqueries within the original query**

```
SELECT
    PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME,
    Sum(Query4.SumOfTICKET_AMT) AS SumOfFARES,
    Sum(Query2.SumOfINCENTIVE) AS Incentive
FROM (PASSENGERS 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME, Sum(FARE_LEVEL.TICKET_AMT) AS SumOfTICKET_AMT
        FROM PASSENGERS LEFT OUTER JOIN FARE_LEVEL ON PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME = FARE_LEVEL.PASSENGER_NAME
        GROUP BY PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME 
    ) AS Query4
    ON PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME = Query4.PASSENGER_NAME)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME, Sum(INCENTIVE_LOG.INCENTIVE) AS SumOfINCENTIVE
        FROM PASSENGERS LEFT OUTER JOIN INCENTIVE_LOG ON PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME = INCENTIVE_LOG.PASSENGER_NAME
        GROUP BY PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME
    ) AS Query2
    ON PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME = Query2.PASSENGER_NAME
GROUP BY PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME;
```

Comment: Are the ID fields key fields? Your problem seems more of a table design issue than a query issue. Why are you linking on the Passengers_name instead of the ID field? Also the ID's do not match between tables, ie... Joen Wright is ID = 1 in PASSSENGERS, ID = 1, 6,7 in FARE_LEVEL and 2, 3 in INCENTIVE_LOG

Comment: The ID fields are the keys for each table and are autogenerated per row. In the tables I am looking at the only way to relate incentive and fare to an individual is via PASSENGER_NAME

Comment: I think that is really the issue here, its a table design problem. The ID should probably be autonumbered for the Passenger table and not the others. This way the keys will match between tables. Your query looks good beyond that though

Comment: I am not able to change the structure of the FARE_LEVEL and INCENTIVE_LOG tables, but I am not sure how the matching IDs would function any different than matching names from the PASSENGERS table? It would still run into the same issue I would think

Comment: what is the purpose of your key fields then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sum the incentives first:

```
SELECT PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME,
     Count(INCENTIVE_LOG.INCENTIVE) AS CountOfINCENTIVE,
     Sum(INCENTIVE_LOG.INCENTIVE) AS SumOfINCENTIVE
FROM (select PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME, 
           Sum(FARE_LEVEL.TICKET_AMT) AS SumOfFARES
      From PASSENGERS 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN FARE_LEVEL 
                ON PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME = FARE_LEVEL.PASSENGER_NAME
      Group by PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME
      ) x
     INNER JOIN INCENTIVE_LOG 
          ON x.PASSENGER_NAME = INCENTIVE_LOG.PASSENGER_NAME
GROUP BY PASSENGERS.PASSENGER_NAME;
```

Also, you can just create a first query that just calculates the summed incentives then use that query in this summary.

Comment: That makes sense, however when I tried to use your version of the query I get the error "Your query does not include the specified expression "PASSENGER_NAME" as a part of an aggregate function.

Comment: I took your advice and created two queries to get the summed incentives (and fares) and then combined them into one and it is now returning the correct results; I included this query in the main post

Comment: sorry I missed the group by in the subquery version. added it in just now. cheers!